# Sync FTP with master branch

Tags: git, ftp

There have been some issues with our website, and changes have been done directly on the webserver via FTP. However, we use git-ftp to sync our master with our FTP, however, if we want to update our website now, we will be overruling our changes made by hand. What is an easy way to sync all changes made online with the master branch of our repo?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use ftp to get back an archive of the website *before* uploading master.

That way, you can unzip that archive on your local repo and check if there are any modifications (done on the live server).
Then, once those modifications have been added/merge without conflict on the local repo, you can use ftp to upload the updated master.

Comment: So, I would download my live website. Where do I download it to? Do I have to add it to an other branche, in order to perform a diff? It would really help me (and probably also others, because I couldnt find this question elsewhere on the internet) if you could go further in details on this process.

Comment: @AE_MM you can extract it directly in the working tree currently checked out to another branch made before your new commits): if the files are different, a git status will detect it: merge that dedicated branch to your master.

Comment: So, I create another branch, commit my current files etc, and then just overwrite everything? Thats also a question that got me thinking, when I switch branches, do my files get changed? In other words, if I overwrite everything in a new branche, and then I switch back to an old branch, I still have my old files?

Comment: The idea is to have committed files only, that way you don't have to worry about overwritten files, and you can merge branches if needed.